# cant skip the elementnotfound exception in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver, instagram

#this is how i coded it

```py
def doesnt_exist(cmt):
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return True
    else:
        return False

cmt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')
if doesnt_exist(cmt):
    print('Skiped - comments disabled')
    press('Right')
else:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').send_keys(random.choice(commentsDict))
    press('enter')
    sleep(3)
    like=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_aamw"]/button/div[2]/span').click()
    press('Right')
    sleep(3)
```

#this a auto commenting instagram bot
while commenting when ever a post comes with "comments disabled" the codes does continue loop and shows error.

please give me the correct code for skipping the posts having comments turned off.

Comment: to reproduce problem we need url with elements or html

Comment: can you please give me a code that runs instagram and comments on posts based on given hashtag. by the use of python selenium webdriver. i dont know much about coding but i need this really hard , please help me with that .

Comment: Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish. However:

You coded `doesn_exist` to take one argument yet the function definition is not referencing it. Moreover, and the cause of your problem, is that you are executing the method call `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')` *twice* -- once within `doesn_exist` within a `try` block to catch exceptions and once in the code that is calling `doesnt_exist`, but not within a try block and this latter call is undoubtedly what is causing your exception. I can see no purpose to your doing this. Soone possibility is:

```py
def doesnt_exist():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if doesnt_exist():
    print('Skiped - comments disabled')
    press('Right')
else:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').send_keys(random.choice(commentsDict))
    press('enter')
    sleep(3)
    like=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_aamw"]/button/div[2]/span').click()
    press('Right')
    sleep(3)
```

Or another possibility, depending upon what your actual intention is as follows:

```py
def doesnt_exist(cmt):
    # Print passed comment (but where?). I am inserting print statement here:
    print(cmt)
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# This is a string:
cmt = '''driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea')'''
if doesnt_exist(cmt):
    print('Skiped - comments disabled')
    press('Right')
else:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class ="_aidk"]//textarea').send_keys(random.choice(commentsDict))
    press('enter')
    sleep(3)
    like=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_aamw"]/button/div[2]/span').click()
    press('Right')
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: this a bot that comments on posts based on specific hashtag. while commenting there are some posts whose comments are disabled.so i am trying to skip those posts and continue commenting on next post . i dont know much about python and selenium,.i am just using it for my bussiness purpose .